# Python Pickle, Loading Issue when returning to list

Tags: python, python-2.7, pickle

I am using pickle to serialize a list of objects, encrypting the serialized string and then using pickle to dump it into a file so that I can be read out in reverse later. I understand this may be a round about way of doing things but in theory I cant seem to get my head around why when reloading the data it continues to fail. Let me first apologize for my horrendous naming conventions one day these will improve.
I have dumped the code below, the error only occurs at the very end when loading the data back into the list and fails with the following error:

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "servertest.py", line 453, in <module>
  mylist = mary1.ReadFromFile()
  File "servertest.py", line 142, in ReadFromFile
  mrylist = pickle.loads(datastring)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 1388, in loads
  return Unpickler(file).load()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 864, in load
  dispatch[key](self)
  KeyError: '\xa7'
```

I have printed the data out at each step when calling both the write and read functions and it appears to be fine:

This is rawdata

```
]q ((c__main__
User
q☺oq☻}q♥(U☻idq♦U♦daveq♣U♥pinq♠U☻22qub(h☺o}q     (h♦U♦maryq
h♠U♥434q♂ube.
```

this is encrypt data

```
 '▼ES╬NZ┴w▲sæô▄Hó^┴☻½K◄6►ëΘ░¡√╡▼/ⁿ♀*a]ì╡
5åα¬δ⌡D╓£o¶α{ô √■♣í♠.|H^E«√☼Hwñ/cúw╠Σ√↔↔╞╞┼3
```

this is enc data

```
  '▼ES╬NZ┴w▲sæô▄Hó^┴☻½K◄6►ëΘ░¡√╡▼/ⁿ♀*a]ì╡
5åα¬δ⌡D╓£o¶α{ô √■♣í♠.|H^E«√☼Hwñ/cúw╠Σ√↔↔╞╞┼3
```

unencrypted data

```
]q ((c__main__
User
q☺oq☻}q♥(U☻idq♦U♦daveq♣U♥pinq♠U☻22qub(h☺o}q     (h♦U♦maryq
           h♠U♥434q♂ube.
```

The following shows the two functions I'm using:

```
def WriteToFile(self, mrlist):        

    self.mrlist = mrlist
    rawdata = pickle.dumps(mrlist, 1)

    #print 'rawdata1\n' + rawdata

    #encrypt pickled list (call on my encryption functions)
    encrydata = self.encryptmessage.EncrMsg(rawdata)

    print('this is encrypt data \n ' + encrydata)

    #Open and dump encrypted string to file
    file=open(self.fn,"wb")
    pickle.dump(encrydata, file, 1)

    file.close()

#Function to call when reading the file
def ReadFromFile(self):

    mrylist = []
    #open file and load
    file = open(self.fn, "rb")
    encdata = pickle.load(file)
    file.close

    print('this is enc data*********\n  ' + encdata)
    #Decrypt the string        
    datastring = self.encrytmessage.DeCryptMsh(encdata)

    print 'unencrypted data' + datastring
    mrylist = pickle.loads(datastring)
    return mrylist`
```

Edit:
The following shows the simple user class for those interested in seeing what the list contains:

```
class User:
def __init__(self, id, pin):
    self.id = id
    self.pin = pin
def getpair(self):
    return ' %s " | " %s ' % (self.id, self.pin)

def edit_pin(self, pin1):
    self.pin = pin1
```

Comment: The code is full of errors. `datastring = self.encrytmessage.DeCryptMsh(encdata)`,  `file.close`, Why did you use *pickle* for the writing/reading the the message to/from file (instead of `file.write` / `file.read`)? What does the `User` class (and the instance that you're trying to handle) look like?

Comment: Hi, I've updated the post with the User class. I will end up using file.write which i hope will get around the issue I'm having but I'd stick like to try and figure out what the issue actually is. I've been doing Python for just over a week and it seems I'm missing something very simple here.

Comment: [\[SO\]: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (mcve)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). The unencrypted / decrypted data seems to be the same (I din't check thoroughly). Try to elliminate irrelevant parts, e.g. crypting, file, etc. Try pickling and unpickling the object immediately after. If the problem reproduces, only place that code, and the object creation as well.

Answer (score 0):

Solution
I managed to get this sorted, my original way of doing this was working fine and it wasn't actually an issue with pickle at all. It appears that my initialisation vector when calling my decryption function differed from when it was originally encrypted. 
This still produced an identical string when decryption took place but must have included some differences i was unable to see. I've rewritten the ReadWrite class to make use of Read and Write functions rather than using pickle to dump the serialised/encrypted list into the file. I have also started writing the IV to an external so that it can be read by the decrypt method the next time the program loads.
Thank you for any help and suggestions given.